# How to exit telnet session via command line using azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, cmd, command-line, ftp, telnet

I am trying to test connectivity from source to a FTP server on port 22 using azure devops commandline tool in pipelines

Command for testing: `telnet TestSFTP02 22`

How do I make sure the telnet connectivity is closed after running this command via the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to kill the `telnet` process. For example like this:

```
(timeout /T 5 > nul && taskkill /f /im telnet.exe > nul) | telnet TestSFTP02 22
```

---

Or use more powerful scripting language, like PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below in your Azure pipeline file, This **WORKED** for me.
Note: Agent OS is Linux

```
- task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        telnet <YOUR-IP> <YOUR-PORT>
        echo "exit"
```

Telnet will exit in one minute time